# Huge memory use difference between dask and dask.distributed

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I am trying to use `dask.delayed` to compute a large matrix for use in a later calculation. I am only ever running the code on a single local machine. When I use a `dask` single-machine scheduler it works fine, but is a little slow. To access more options and performance monitors to improve the code I would like to use `dask.distributed` on a single machine. However running the same code with a `dask.distributed` client slowly eats up all available memory and crashes without achieving anything.

Is there a different way of setting up the problem that would allow the `dask.distributed` client to complete with better memory efficiency?

- I read through the dask.delayed [Best Practices guide](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html?highlight=best%20practices) and think we are using it right.
- I have run it on a local Win 10 PC (64GB RAM) and an Azure Win Server 2012 VM (256 GB), with the same result.
- I have tried setting chunks manually.
- I have tried using `stack.rechunk` to optimise the chunk sizes, including auto chunking by rows and columns (chunks of rows seems to run way faster in the `dask` scheduler).
- I have tried using `compute()` and `persist()` (same outcome).
- I have tried starting the `dask.distributed` client with both threads and processes scheduler and tweaking the number of workers. `threads` uses even more RAM faster before dying.
- I have tried setting up `dask.distributed` with a memory limit `cluster = distributed.LocalCluster(memory_limit = 8e9)` as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998272/dask-memory-management-with-default-scheduler), but the memory limit is ignored.
- If I reduce the size of the problem (`nX` and `nY` below) the `dask.distributed` client does complete the task, however it still requires vastly more time and memory than the `dask` scheduler.

This example reproduces the problem:

```py
import dask
import distributed
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

def calcRow(X,Y):
    Tx = np.transpose(X * (X + Y)) # Simplified work
    return (Tx)

# Specify size of (nY x nX) matrix
nX = 1000000 #  Distributed fails with nX >= 1000000 and nY >= 5000
nY = 5000

# Fill with random data
x = np.random.rand(nX,1)
y = np.random.rand(nY,1)

# Setup dask.distributed client.
# Comment out these two lines to use the standard dask scheduler,
# which does work 
client = distributed.Client()
client

# Build the matrix
row = dask.delayed(calcRow, pure=True)   # Build 1 row
makeRows = [row(x, y[ii]) for ii in range(nY)] # Loop for all nY rows
buildMat = [da.from_delayed(makeRow, dtype=float, shape=(10,nX))
            for makeRow in makeRows] # Build matrix
stack = da.vstack(buildMat)
my_matrix = stack.compute() # Calculate the matrix entries
```

In reality my problems are much larger, and `calcRow` is a large, slow, complex calculation itself, but the shape and matrix build steps are the same.

I understand best practice is to `scatter` the data into memory before calling `compute`, but I don't have a function to scatter, just a `delayed` array.

If I comment out the 2 `dask.distributed` client lines, the above example runs in 60 secs using a max of 0.25 GB of RAM. But with those lines in, the code climbs to full memory use (64GB) in 3-4 minutes and keeps going until the system becomes unstable.

If I build the matrix in `dask` I can then start a `dask.distributed` client, and use the matrix in later `dask.distributed` calculations with no problem. It is just building the matrix that causes problems.

I almost feel that this is a bug, but can't be sure my code isn't to blame. I would really value suggestions that might can get the code to run, or prove a bug.

**EDIT 1:**
I also tried appling a decorator to `calcRow`:

```py
@dask.delayed
def calcRow(X,Y):
```

and using:

```py
makeRows = [calcRow(x, y[ii]) for ii in range(nY)]
```

but that seems to be identical?

**EDIT 2:**
If I start the `distributed.client` with `processes=False` it consumes all system memory faster, but actually provides the following warning, which may be diagnostic:

> distributed.worker - WARNING - Memory use is high but worker has no data to
>   store to disk.  Perhaps some other process is leaking memory?  Process 
>   memory: 40.27 GB -- Worker memory limit: 8.00 GB

Comment: What are you using your matrix for? If it is matrix-vector  or matrix- matrix multiplication you might want to delay the compute until then, since you would never need to have the full matrix in memory.

Comment: That is definitely an option for some of the problems @JuanCarlosRamirez . We can call `results = da.dot(stack, x).compute()` and be done. But because of the size of most problems and the complexity of later compute steps (a matrix inversion) we save the matrix to disk using zarr `G = da.to_zarr(stack, path_to_zarr)` either for use in later calculations in this run, or for later runs. That call seems to trigger an implicit `compute()` call, which ends up with the same problem described above.