# dask processes scheduler is not performing well

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, dask

I define a cpu-bound function

```
def countdown(n):
    while n > 0:
        n -= 1
```

running `countdown(50000000)` takes 2.16 seconds on my laptop.

First, I test `multiprocess` parallelization.

```
from multiprocess import Pool
with Pool(2) as p:
    l=p.map(countdown,[50000000,50000000])
```

takes 2.46 seconds, which is a good parallelization.

Then, I test `dask` processes scheduler parallelization

```
l=[dask.delayed(countdown)(50000000),dask.delayed(countdown)(50000000)]
dask.compute(l,scheduler='processes',num_workers=2)
```

however, it takes 4.53 seconds. This is the same speed as

```
dask.compute(l,scheduler='threads',num_workers=2)
```

**What is wrong with dask processes scheduler? I expected it should be on a par with multiprocess**

Comment: If this is a bug or an unexpected behavior, it could be a good idea to [post an issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/) so Dask developers can improve this.

Answer (score 1):

The following works, so I'm not sure if the above is a bug or a feature:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client

with Client(n_workers=2) as client:
    l=[dask.delayed(countdown)(50000000),dask.delayed(countdown)(50000000)]
    dask.compute(*l)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is indeed works. But I intentionally avoid using distributed. Because I found distributed Client consumes unreasonably huge memory sometimes. There are some post talking about this like https://stackoverflow.com/q/56779254/1911722

Comment: Thanks, I was also surprised when I could reproduce your results... to me it seems like a bug, but I don't have a good enough understanding to be sure...

Comment: > Client consumes unreasonably huge memory <. This situation should be solved too. The distributed scheduler is generally recommended over multiprocessing, even on a single machine.